# how to restart jboss server using command prompt

Tags: jboss

I have a maven script which is connecting to SVN and checking out the code and it is deployed to the deployment folder of JBoss. Can anyone tell me how to restart the JBoss server please using the command prompt?? I am using JBoss 6.0.0.GA.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From you JBOSS_HOME dir /bin/standalone.sh or /bin/standalone.bat.

You can shut it down with CTRL-c.

That is the specific answer to the specific question you asked.  Is there more going on here?

Comment: OP's question is how to restart the JBoss server not to shut down the jBoss server.

Answer (score 0):

In jBoss AS 7.1.1 Final and all new versions after, including the Current version, WildFly 17 (***JBoss*** is now ***WildFly***) you can actually re-start.

**You do not need to shut down** with `CTRL-C`

Open a new command window and keep it side by side with the current running command window, so that you can see the re-start.

from command prompt goto  WildFly installation folder

(eg. `"C:\Program Files\WildFly\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\bin\"` ) and execute

```
jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:reload
```

(eg. `C:\Program Files\WildFly\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\bin\>jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:reload` )

In Linux: `$ ./jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:reload`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the exact answer to the question, but is the first result for mine:

How to restart wildfly?

```
sudo service wildfly restart
```

[There are also](http://www.itbuzzpress.com/wildfly-8-administration/getting-started-with-wildfly-8.html) `top`, `start` and so on options